Are we able to compute electrochemical potentials of metals?
When we put into contact a copper and a zinc plate some electrons will move from one metal to the other due to a difference in the electrochemical potential of the two metals (see for example the answer to this question). My question is: are we able to compute (not to measure) the electrochemical potential of metals? And if we are able, which methods do we use?
EDIT
The answer could be simple "no" or, if it is a "yes", I'd like to know first from which data it is possible do compute the electrochemical potential of metals. For example, is it a property that depends only on the metal or also on the temperature or even on the surface details of the metal? Moreover I'd like to know the name and if possible a brief sketch of a method that is used for the calculation.

From what data would you "compute" it, and why, when it's by itself the easily observable data?

@mithoron right, why would anybody care that the easily observable and measurable inertial mass is proportional to the equally easily observable and measurable gravitational mass?

This might get more traction on https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

@Mithoron Ideally from the number of protons of the metal atoms. Maybe other variables are relevant such as the temperature. The reason why I'm interested in the calculation is that I don't undersand the electrochemical potential properly and I think that knowing how it is computed can help me to undersand it better. I'll try to clarify this in the question.

@Anyon thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to clarify the question here first.

The electrode potential is related to the free energy $\Delta G$ for the reaction $M \to M^{n+} + ne$, so the answer is that it depends if we can calculate $\Delta G$. This isn't my field, but I think this is a hard calculation to do from first principles.

@JohnRennie Thanks. I had a look at what is done and indeed it seems that they compute the free energy first. Unfortunately I'm not able to follow the details at the moment.
